What should I use to create an android messenger?
I'm new to Android but I'm trying to figure it out. So I need my app to

Send messages (and other info) to my server
Recieve messages online from server
Recieve notification about new message when app is inactive

I've learned that you can use socketio to create bidirectional communication. But I dont understand how to keep recieving messages when my app isn't active since documentation clearly disapproves using background service and I don't want to notify user about constant connection (foreground service). Is there another way to do this?
P.S. I can use and change literally anything except the part where all the data should be kept on my server

So you didn't find: https://developer.android.com/social-and-messaging/guides

You use push messaging.  Look up FCM.

@MorrisonChang sorry, forgot to metion FCM is banned in my country

Then you have little choice other than "notify user about constant connection (foreground service)" or infrequent polling (if you can live with that).

You can use Firebase. Create a Firebase account with your Google account. Then link your app with Firebase. Under the Tools menu, you can see the Firebase setting in your Android Studio.
Then choose the messaging method as your preference.
Good luck with coding!
